# Widespread incorrect use of the [redirect] tag

Tags: discussion, status-review, tags, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

The description of the [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirect) tag states:

> A response by a webserver, that asks the user agent to not show the response body, but instead request a different resource. Questions can be related to Redirect Protocols, Link Equity and Types of Redirects.

However, there are several questions where this has been used for questions about redirecting stdout/stderr. For example, doing a search for [`[stdout] [redirect]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdout+redirect) gives me over 200 results, and most of the ones on the first page involve redirecting output streams.

(Possibly all of them did, I didn't have time to read them all in detail.)

There is a [redirectstandardoutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirectstandardoutput) tag which would fit some of these cases, but no equivalent [redirectstandarderror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirectstandarderror)

I do not have enough rep to edit that many posts in a row - IIRC I can have at most five in the review queue waiting for approval - so I'm hoping that mods or higher-rep users can act on this and remove the tag *en masse* from the relevant posts.

Comment: `redirectstandardoutput` is a horrible tagname, IMO.

Comment: We had url-redirection but that became a synonym https://stackoverflow.com/tags/redirect/synonyms

Comment: We already have [http-status-code-301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-301), for what it's worth. (And [302](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-302),  [303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-303), [307](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-307) and [308](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-308) as well!).

Comment: Again... who is hurt by this? Just fix questions as you come across them naturally and you won't disrupt the natural order of things. There is no need to edit anything en masse, nobody will be helped by that. Except people who have a severe OCD when it comes to tags. As long as people tag like we're on Twitter and people refuse to read tag descriptions, they'll keep popping up on the wrong questions. Trying to curate that as a whole at this point in time is the act of ice skating uphill. I mean who in their right mind is going to use "redirectstandardoutput" ? No. Redirect of course.

Comment: At this point we might as well add the second meaning to the tag excerpt and be done with it.

Comment: @Gimby The goal of posts like these is to make sure we don't have bad tagging. I agree that [thistagisreallyspecific] is not a helpful convention, but neither is "Just periodically clean it up".

Comment: What if we renamed it to [web-redirect] and cleaned the tag some?

Comment: if anything [web-redirect] is an awful proposal.

Comment: I’d prefer [http-redirect] myself.

Comment: Given the continued lack of development of the tagging system and UI, I think it's fairer to describe a tag as being ambiguous, rather than blame the users for "incorrect use". In the desktop UI, tag descriptions are shown briefly as you type, or if you know to leave your mouse in one place for two seconds; in the mobile UI, they are entirely absent. Unless and until that changes, users _will_ tag things based on their intuition, not tag descriptions, and we should manage tags on that basis.

Comment: @IMSoP found the UX specialist.

Comment: Most people should be [redirect]ed to other tags.

Comment: @rene well, [blame Microsoft for the naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=net-8.0)...

Answer (score 39):

I suggest that the [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirect) tag be deprecated with an eye toward eventual burnination, and in its place, encourage the use of [http-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-redirect) for web redirection questions, and a new tag, perhaps [stream-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream-redirect) or [io-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io-redirect) be created and use encouraged for questions involving redirection of streams (stdio, stderr, powershell's info, etc.).

(In response to comments:) I’ve since learned that there is also an [https-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/https-redirect) tag; it might make sense to merge them (and any specific web-redirects, such as [redirectwithcookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirectwithcookies)), though I’m not firm in either camp on that question. There is also an [io-redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io-redirection) tag that looks like it should serve for my suggested [io-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io-redirect) when dealing with bash, powershell, winbatch, etc.; for redirection that is not implemented by the shell, perhaps [stream-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream-redirect) would still be suitable.

Comment: I would say these tag names should consistently use `-redirection` instead of `-redirect`.

Comment: What is "powershell's info"?

Comment: I feel we'd be better served changing the usage to use the existing 3xx tags linked by yivi above, (eg  [tag:http-status-code-301], and just adding some more generic synonyms (eg `301-redirect`, `301-moved-permanently`),  rather than attempting to maintain a `http(s)-redirect` tag on top.

Comment: @Robotnik all 3xx status codes is about http-redirection, and the user may only know that the question is about doing a "http redirection", so I find it difficult to use a specific 3xx-tag in the general case.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - PowerShell has iostreams other than stdin, stdout, and stderr that can be redirected; one of them is the 'info' stream (I forget the number, offhand) and is the stream that's "fed" by the `Write-Information` cmdlet. I _believe_ that the output of `-Verbose` and `Write-Warning` are also separate redirectable streams in PowerShell.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Consistency would be a Good Thing, yes; I don't particularly care either way whether it's `-redirect` or `-redirection`.

Comment: Stack Exchange should create the concept of a "disambiguation tag" where it lists all the possible more specific variants and when you try to use it, it asks you to choose one.  Old questions with the tag could keep using the tag until edited.

Comment: Reminds me of disambiguation categories on English Wikipedia. Example: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stamps>

Comment: @StephenOstermiller that looks exactly like something that SE has said it will never do due performance constrains.

Comment: It look like `[io-redirection]` may need its description changed if it's going to be used as described here. For instance, redirecting standard output to a file isn't covered by that description because it isn't "an input to another command".

Comment: @AJM - administrative detail; the question is whether this overall solution or some other proposal is to be implemented. It's good to note it, but I'm sure the admins who would implement it (if it is to be implemented) will dot all the I's and cross all the T's (or vice-versa, as indicated).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin If so, then I think it's probably time I gave the green tick to this answer. I'm not that familiar with meta, so is there any reason I can't mark this answer as accepted?

Comment: @AJM - I think the idea here is to let the admins decide; they have specialty tags such as [tag:under-review] to indicate what the status of proposals such as this are. Meta works differently from the main stack; I'm admittedly not entirely clear on _all_ the nuances.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks, I'll hold off on the tick then.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "I would say these tag names should consistently use `-redirection` instead of `-redirect`" - FWIW I strongly prefer the other way round: `-redirect` over `-redirection`. I'm curious why you would prefer `-redirection` here? Nearly all of these tags already use `-redirect`. `io-redirection` is the only one that doesn't. `redirection` (and `url-redirection`) are synonym(s) of `redirect`. (The only other tag on SO that uses "redirection" is the `redirection-wordpress-plugin` tag - in this case "Redirection" is the name of the product.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I'm with MrWhite on this.  When you talk about an HTTP 3xx response, you call it a "redirect", and that's the directive or keyword used in some mainstream server config files.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Apache_HTTP_Server_mod_rewrite).  The Wikipedia article is titled "URL redirection" because its trying to sound formal in its description of the subject.  `[io-redirection]` sounds good to me since the tag covers various ways to do it, like the `dup2` system call, not just shell operators like `>>`.  Hrm, how broad is `[url-redirect]` supposed to be?

Answer (score 3):

I merged [https-redirect] into [http-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-redirect), because there is no difference there.

[redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirect) is too large to merge into that same tag (via mod tooling). I have added [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) for a Dev to come along and perform the merge.

Comment: FWIW `https-redirect` and `http-redirect` are/were not the same thing. An `https-redirect` was generally used for an "HTTP to HTTPS redirect" (aka an "HTTPS redirect" - a specific type of `http-redirect`). However, I still don't think this warranted its own tag (and probably better served with two existing tags: `http-redirect` and `https`).